# How to make sure that a Javascript function is called after EVERY postback in Liferay/ICEFaces?

Tags: javascript, liferay, icefaces

I have very little experience with Liferay and ICEFaces. I need to build a portlet that calls a specific Javascript function every time a postback occurs.

In fact, when the form is submitted through AJAX, a loading screen appears and blocks the screen. When the postback completes, I need to take it out and give control to user again.

I have tried to put the `<script>` snippet in the portlet's body and it succeeds in executing when the page is first loaded (it's ok) and also when a postback changes the page's HTML content.

The problem is, when the server doesn't change the HTML (ie. a search returned with no result, you search again and you still get no results) the function is not executed again.

Even if I could post some code, I have very little idea of the architecture the web application is built on. What I gave here is all the information I have. By editing the javascript function to emit alerts when it's called I found the behaviour of the page.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it using a weird trick with random numbers I want to share.

First, in the backing bean property I created a method

```
public String getLoadFunction()
{
    return "functionName("+ new Random().nextDouble() +");";
}
```

and then

```
<script>
    #{MyViewBean.loadFunction}
</script>
```

"Simply", ICEFaces is so smart it checks if the HTML has been modified or not when processing AJAX requests. This trick is very similar to appending a random number to HTTP URLs to avoid caches.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following:

```
<script>
    Ice.onSendReceive('document:body',
        function(){/*Before send ajax request*/},
        function(){/*After receive the response*/}
    );
</script>
```

But this solution applied for every ajax request you made, hope this can help you.

Comment: Suppose other code uses this function somewhere (the project is big, I don't have control over all code), does a new cal to Ice.onSendReceive **append** or **overwrite** callbacks? I was already forced to implement appending callbacks for another feature because my portlets don't know if other portlets use the same features and could go into conflict